# JavaScript: Generate random number generated arrays

Tags: javascript

I am making integration test for my app. I would like to see how cartItems payload my db can write. For that, I have generated cartItems array. Inside that array I have one item called ean. I would like to generate 12 digits random number to ean. But it always return me same number from the array.

I have facing two issue

1. Could not able generate 12 digits ean number
2. When I generate the arrays and the 6 digits ean number always same. But I want random numbers

**Here is my code**

```js
  const requestParameters = {
        id: "530d275e-5de1-466d-86fe-3993a2563fb6",
        cartItems: new Array(500).fill({
          additionalInfo: '',
          brand: '',
          replace: false,
          basicQuantityUnit: 'KPL',
          collectingPriority: 1000,
          ean: Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000) + 10000, // I want to render random 12 digits
          id: '0200097823340',
          itemCount: '1'
        })
    }
    
    console.log(requestParameters)
```

Comment: don't use `.fill`. use a loop and `.push` to recompute

Comment: The `fill()` content is generated once and then applied to all elements of the array. To do what you need you'll have to loop manually and generate the number in every iteration.

Comment: Could you please show me in code?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a `for` loop...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've inserted the same item `500` times, but you wanted to create a new one every time. Use `map` to do this

```js
const requestParameters = {
  id: "530d275e-5de1-466d-86fe-3993a2563fb6",
  cartItems: new Array(5).fill().map(() => ({
    additionalInfo: '',
    brand: '',
    replace: false,
    basicQuantityUnit: 'KPL',
    collectingPriority: 1000,
    ean: Array(12).fill().map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).join(''),
    id: '0200097823340',
    itemCount: '1'
  }))
}

console.log(requestParameters)
```

To generate 12 digits I would use:

```
Array(12).fill().map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).join('')
```

and if you want it as a number instead of a string use:

```
+Array(12).fill().map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)).join('')
```

Comment: Just be aware that this will create 2 arrays, the original `Array(5)` which is empty and the new one generated by `map()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  `Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000) + 10000` return 6 digit. I want 12 digit

Answer (score 1):

```
Math.floor(100000000000 + Math.random() * 900000000000)
```

This generates 12 digit random numbers and makes sure the first number isn't 0

Comment: and you can actually format numbers in js `900_000_000_000` or use the scientific notation `9e11`

Comment: so it is : `Math.floor(1e11 + Math.random() * 9e11)` (or  `0|(1e11 + Math.random() * 9e11)`)